# How to validate the input in vector

Tags: c++, vector

I tried to validate the user input using a vector in c++. I almost searched for a possible solution but I can't find the solution.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> selectFloor = {};
    int maxfloor, currentfloor = 1, select, i, k, inputFloor;

    cout << "How many floors do you want for your elevator? : ";
    cin >> maxfloor;
    cout << "----------This Elevator have " << maxfloor << " Floors---------";
    cout << "\n";

    while(true)
    {
        cout << "select how many floor to select : ";
        cin >> select;

        // Insert
        for(i = 0; i < select; i++)
        {
            cout << "Select floor : ";
            cin >> inputFloor;
            selectFloor.push_back(inputFloor);
        }

        //This is my validation if the input already exist
        if(selectFloor.begin(), selectFloor.end(), inputFloor)
        {
            cout << "Already selected" << endl;
            selectFloor.pop_back(); // pop the last same input
            // Display the input
            for(k = 0; k < selectFloor.size(); k++)
                std::cout << selectFloor.at(k) << ' ';
            break;
        }
    } // end while

    return 0;
}
```

This is my example output. I enter 4 floors but the last pop

```
select how many floor to select : 4
Select floor : 1
Select floor : 2
Select floor : 3
Select floor : 4
Already selected
1 2 3
```

I want to this if there so no same number

```
select how many floor to select : 4
    Select floor : 1
    Select floor : 2
    Select floor : 3
    Select floor : 4
   
    1 2 3 4
```

but if the input is already existed this the example

```
select how many floor to select : 4
    Select floor : 1
    Select floor : 2
    Select floor : 3
    Select floor : 3
    Already selected
    1 2 3
```

Comment: Do you have to use a vector? Unless this is a homework assignment, using `unordered_set` would make more sense. It ensures its contents are unique.

Comment: @MustafaOzturk Yes, because I want to familiarize what vector actually do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `if(selectFloor.begin(),selectFloor.end(),inputFloor)`

This if condition is an expression with two comma operators where each operand is evaluated from left to right and each except the last one is discarded. Since the first two operands don't have side effects their evaluation does nothing and the above is equivalent with:

```
if (inputFloor)
```

Which is clearly not what you want.

---

You need [`std::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find):

```
if (std::find(selectFloor.begin(), selectFloor.end(), inputFloor) != selectFloor.end())
```

or C++20's [`std::ranges::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/find):

```
if (std::ranges::find(selectFloor, inputFloor) != selectFloor.end())
```

---

There are other problems with your code like you need to check if the input exists for each input.

Comment: Hi I tried this but still the same output.

Comment: @woofMaranon as I've said there are other problems with your code. If you are going to learn you need to step through your code with a debugger line by line and inspect each variable how is modified.

Comment: @woofMaranon Suggestion: Check if the entered floor already exists in the vector _before_ you `push_back` it into the vector. If you `push_back` before `find`, it will _always_ find it, right?

Comment: What Ted said is the kind of thing that you will discover yourself by using a debugger.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing wrong in here:

```cpp
if(selectFloor.begin(), selectFloor.end(), inputFloor)
```

Which makes no scenes, the result of `,` operator in the condition will be the value of `inputFloor`  to be checked. You need to check if `selectFloor` contains the value of `inputFloor` and you could use `std::any_of` or better `std::find`:

```
if (selectFloor.cend() != std::find(selectFloor.cbegin(), selectFloor.cend(), inputFloor)
```